# How can I use asyncio.Condition within a Task in Python < v3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Any reason why I can't use a asyncio.Condition within a Task?

```
c = asyncio.Condition()

async def a():
    print("A ..")
    # await asyncio.sleep(0.2) # This works
    async with c:
        # RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<a() running at ..this file..:13>> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
        await c.wait()   #

async def main():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(a())
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

Says: "Got Future  attached to a different loop"

I don't *think* I created a new loop.

Full example here:

```
import asyncio

c = asyncio.Condition()

async def a():
    print("A ..")
    # await asyncio.sleep(0.2) # This works
    async with c:
        # RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<a() running at ..this file..:13>> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
        await c.wait()   #
    print("A done")

async def b():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("B ..")
    async with c:
       c.notify_all() 
    print("B done")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(a())
    await b()

asyncio.run(main())
```

I see the same error using, Python 3.7. 3.8, 3.9.

Comment: Using Python 3.10.2, your code runs the first time I execute it but fails afterwards, even though no event loops remain active (according to `asyncio.get_event_loop()`.

Comment: I verified that this is the case. Works in 3.10, fails in 3.7, 3.8, 3.9

Answer (score 1):

The docs for `asyncio.Condition.notify_all()` states:

> The lock must be acquired before this method is called and released shortly after. If called with an unlocked lock a RuntimeError error is raised.

The lock gets released in `a` on calling `c.wait()`, therefore the `Lock` inside `c` is unlocked when you call `c.notify_all()`.

You need to hold the lock before calling `notify_all()`. Using

```py
 async with c:
     c.notify_all()
```

makes your example work as expected.

UPDATE

I tested this only on Python 3.10.1 where it worked like this. In fact it fails when I run it on Python 3.8.5. But the problem here stems of the use of the `Condition` as a global variable. In your example the `Condition` is created before the event loop is created, so I assume it is not correctly attached to the event loop that is created later.
I updated your example in a way, that the `Condition` is created with a running loop. This makes the example work again in Python 3.8.5:

```py
import asyncio

async def a(c):
    print("A ..")
    async with c:
        await c.wait()
    print("A done")

async def b(c):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("B ..")
    async with c:
        c.notify_all()
    print("B done")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    c = asyncio.Condition() # loop already running
    asyncio.create_task(a(c)) # get_event_loop() also works but the use is discouraged in the docs
    await b(c)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: No. It fails with the same exception even with your change and even if await b() is commented out.

Comment: I will update the example with the lock though. Thank you.

Comment: I this is requirement?
See my example below - the condition is still created outside of the event loop.
Is it a requirement that condition belong to a loop? If so, how can loop to loop communication be implemented?

Comment: The docs for Condition say only "Changed in version 3.10: Removed the loop parameter."
It was optional before (my implementation just lucky to get the right loop), and not-required now?

Comment: asyncio has changed quite drastically since it became a stdlib in Python 3.4 and this is not easily answered in a comment. The loop parameter has been deprecated for a while and is removed in 3.10 in favor of fetching the running loop when it is needed from the current thread. So in your example in 3.10 the `Condition` only fetches the loop when it needs to create a future, which only happens after the event loop is already running. This is why it works as a global variable here.

Answer (score 0):

As @JanWilamowski points out, this seems to be a bug with Python < v3.10. Works fine in 3.10.

Booo!

It also seems that you can't work around this bug by switching from Condition to Queue (see below) - I guess Queue uses Condition internally.
Simlarly ... this also failed:

```
async def main():
    loop.create_task(a())
    ...

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
# asyncio.run(main())
```

However, for reasons unclear, this *does* work:

```
async def main():
    loop.create_task(a())
    ...

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()   // @@@@
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Full working example below:

```
import asyncio
import time

USE_QUEUE = False

if not USE_QUEUE:
    c = asyncio.Condition()
else:
    q = asyncio.Queue()

async def a():
    print("A ..")
    # await asyncio.sleep(0.2) # This works
    if not USE_QUEUE:
        async with c:
           await c.wait()
    else:
        result = await q.get()
        q.task_done()
        print("result", result)
    print("A done", time.time())

async def b():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("B ..", time.time())
    if not USE_QUEUE:
        async with c:
            c.notify_all()
    else:
        result = await q.put(123)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("B done")

async def main():
    loop.create_task(a())
    # asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(a())
    await b()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```